# Login form is invisible and PHP doesn't show errors

Tags: php, html, mysql

Good day,

I made a login.php, so the user can login into the page. After writing the script and checking the file to find some mistakes I made, the page login.php doesn't show anything. Even the source code displays only `<body></body>`.

Here is the code to make a connection to the database.

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();
$servername = "xx";
$username = "xx";
$password = "xx";
try {
    $conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=xx", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Don't mind the "xx". And no, this is not in my real script.
And now the script for the user to login to the page:

```
//fetch data
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE username=:username");
    $result = $statement->execute(array('username' => $username));
    $user = $statement->fetch();

    //Check password
    if($user !== true && password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
        exit('Anmeldung war erfolgreich. Gehe zurück zu <a href="veranstaltungen.php">der Hauptseite</a>, aber das ist ein Geheimnis.');
    } else {
        $errorMessage = "E-Mail oder Passwort war FALSCH!!<br>";
    }
}
```

And the form, which should be on the page so the user can type in his data to login.

```
<form action="?login=1" method="post">
    <input class="uk-input uk-from-width-medium" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Benutzername eingeben">
    <input class="uk-input uk-from-width-medium" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Passwort">
    <input class="uk-button" type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Sublime Text doesn't also display errors or warnings. Thank you kindly.

Comment: enable error reporting.

Comment: Your form method is post but in php code you are trying to control `isset($_GET['login']) `.

Comment: change isset($_GET['login']) to isset($_POST['login'])

Comment: Guys, it's really weird, but I actually wrote "ini_set" wrong. It was "ni_set" the entire time! I found it by myself. I can't believe it; i sat so many hours infront of that script trying to figure out whats wrong only to find out later the first line is wrong... I cursed for nothing xD But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out what I'm doing wrong here...
The first line

```
ni_set("display_errors", 1);
```

was wrong the entire time. It should be "ini_set("display_errors", 1);". I sat so many hours infront of that script trying to figure out what's wrong here. I cursed for nothing. I just love my job. But still, thank you guys and sorry for the inconvience.